# How to install the nginx manpage when I installed nginx from source?

Tags: nginx, manpage

I installed nginx 1.2.0 from source on ubuntu 12.04 (precise) but it says there is no manpage entry for nginx when I run `man nginx`.

How to I install it?

Answer (score 0):

If there a man directory where you installed it (e.g. `/usr/local/nginx/man`), you can add that path to `/etc/manpath.config`.

Comment: I tried that but `manpath.config` being readonly I don't want to tamper with it. Instead I tried to add the `nginx.1.gz` manpage downloaded from `http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/nginx.1.html` and I put it in /usr/share/man/man1/ then ran `mandb` but it didn't find the new file. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding the line `MANDATORY_MANPATH <directory containing manpage>` to `/etc/manpath.config` If it breaks something, you can just remove that line from the file. You'll need to use sudo to edit the file (e.g., `sudo gedit /etc/manpath.config` from the command line will work).